# Debian Bash Readonly Associative Array Error Redirection

Tags: bash, debian

I've declared a readonly associative array in a script file on Debian Gnu/Linux (version 12.4).

As with a readonly variable, error redirection is easily done as such,

```
readonly AQUA_FG="$(tput setaf 87)" 2> /dev/null
readonly GOLD_FG="$(tput setaf 227)" 2> /dev/null
```

This works well, particularly when or if the script is called or pasted multiple times in a command window. The,

```
bash: AQUA_FG: readonly variable
```

Error isn't displayed in the command window.

If I make an associative readonly array of foreground colours like,

```
readonly -A FORECOLOUR=(
    [AQUA]="$(tput setaf 87)"
    [GOLD]="$(tput setaf 227)"
) 2> /dev/null
```

When this array is declared or pasted in a command window,

```
bash: FORECOLOUR: readonly variable
```

Is displayed.

My question is, is such error redirection possible for readonly associative arrays, or am I not doing something correctly?

Comment: It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message disappears as soon as you mask the line breaks with a backslash and to put the entire thing in single quotes.

Your declaration needs to look like this:

```
readonly -A FORECOLOUR='(\
    [AQUA]="$(tput setaf 87)"\
    [GOLD]="$(tput setaf 227)"\
    )' 2> /dev/null
```

Masking the array declaration as a string makes the entire declaration aware of the error redirection again.

Comment: Yes, that worked, and a few variations of your solution too. That is, the single quotes can be replaced by double quotes, the double quotes around the array values can be removed, as well as the backslashes. I shall mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with another work around for this (error?) for anyone interested.

In a separate bash script file, declare the readonly associative array(s). Eg.

### script-assoc-array

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly -A FORECOLOUR=(
    [AQUA]="$(tput setaf 87)"
    [GOLD]="$(tput setaf 227)"
) 2> /dev/null
```

In a script file where the readonly associative array(s) are required.

### my-task-scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

source "/path/to/script-assoc-array" 2> /dev/null

echo "${FORECOLOUR[GOLD]}"
```

The code in my-task-scripts can be copied and pasted, or my-task-scripts can be called, multiple times the,

```
bash: FORECOLOUR: readonly variable
```

Will not be displayed. It is imperative to redirect the error at the

```
source "/path/to/script-assoc-array" 2> /dev/null
```

level.

Also, I don't know what other consequences there are for redirecting errors at this top level, so I don't recommend it, unless you have a script file of readonly associative arrays.